# React-Router installation wont go further

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

Thats my realy first atemp for Coding. I bought a Video Starting guide for Java and i did some first steps like installing Visual Studio Code and NodeJs. Now the Turtorial says i need to istall react router but if i type npm install react-router-dom --save (in Visual Studio Code) this window in Powershell pop ups and it won't go further. Any Advice for me?

[react-rputer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Be2dG.png)

Comment: npm can be slow... Did It work?

Comment: I let it run for 1h or more. Didn't work. I found this Temp.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cra-template-typescript-husky which had the same Problem then me. But if u run this one i got an other error.

Comment: are you using creat-react-app? did you initialize app correctly with npx? please edit your answer with all the steps you made